# ElasticSearch URI Search null field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I need to create a query via URI to filter all data between two dates and also if this date field is null.

For example:
I have the field "creation_date" in some objects, however I want that in the resulting also does not appear the objects that the field does not have.

I tried something similar below:

```
http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=channel.schedule.creation_date:[2018-06-19 TO 2018-12-22] OR channel.schedule.creation_date: NULL
```

As far as comparing the dates is OK, it works. The problem is to get the NULL values.

**Edited**
Source sample:

```
 "_source": {
                "channel": {
                    "activated": false,
                    "approved": false,
                    "content": "Jvjv",
                    "creation_date": "2018-06-21T13:06:10.000Z",
                    "facebookLink": "J jv",
                    "id": "Kvjvjv",
                    "instagramId": "Jvjv",
                    "name": "Kbkbkvk",
                    "ownerId": "sZtxdhiNbNY9sr2DtiCzlgJfsqb2",
                    "plan": 0,
                    "purpose": "Jvjv",
                    "recurrence": 1,
                    "segment": "Jvjvjv",
                    "twitterId": "Jvjv",
                    "youtubeId": "Jvj"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `NOT(_exists_:field_name)` constraint:

Can you try this ?

```
http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=channel.schedule.creation_date:[2018-06-19 TO 2018-12-22] OR NOT(_exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried this but didn't work

Comment: Can you show a document that is returned but should not?

Comment: In fact it does not return, says that it did not find any value. but in my database today, this field does not exist, ie it should return all data.   RETURN: {
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}

Comment: Do you have some idea about that?

Comment: Btw if I try with this: //elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=(channel.schedule.creation_date:[2018-06-19 TO 2018-12-22])  OR  (_exists_:channel.modification_date)  work well, the problem is when put the NOT

Comment: In your question you wanted to test the `creation_date` field not the `modification_date` one, maybe that's why

Comment: No, it's just creation_date there, I just put the modification_date to test if _exists_ worked, and the function works. The problem is with the NOT clause when placed does not work as expected to filter the nulls.

Comment: Just so we're clear, it's `_exists_` not `exists`. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names). Can you show two documents, one that matches the first condition and a second that should match the second condition?

Comment: Let me try to be a bit more clear, this is exactly the way I'm running: `http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=channel.schedule.creation_date:[2018-06-19 TO 2018-12-22] OR NOT(_exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)` if I dont put in "code" StackOverFlow remove the "underline", but yes I put exactly how you show me.

Comment: Ok, what about my question in my latest comment?

Comment: About your last comment is that.. I put `_exists_` exactly how you told me.. look my query

Comment: No, I meant "Can you show two documents, one that matches the first condition and a second that should match the second condition?"

Comment: I'm sorry I understood now what you mean. with `_exists_`: `{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}` second try with `exist`: `{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}`

Comment: Is the same, but when I remove the NOT, used only `_exists_`: return as well `{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 181,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "channels",
                "_type": "channel",
                "_id": "-LEWNtPgMHEl8Ep-_DKD",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
       `

Comment: But I really need is NULL, the ones that do not have this field.

Comment: `NOT(_exists_)` matches documents which either do not have the field or have the field whose value is null. I'm interested in seeing the source of your document not the response you get.

Comment: One more thing, when I put NOT EXIST without my range of dates (OR) like: `http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?NOT(_exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)`  WORKED AS WELL but when I put my OR with range of dates the results not appear: `http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels/channel/_search?q=channel.schedule.creation_date:[2018-06-19 TO 2018-12-22] OR NOT(_exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)`

Comment: Looking at your source, the name of your field is `channel.creation_date` and not `channel.schedule.creation_date`

Comment: But is exactly what I need.. I dont have this field `channel.schedule.creation_date` in this structure so I need search by them.. `channel.creation_date` is another field....... The source that is in the Issue description is exactly what the query should show me.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping you get from `curl -XGET http://localhost//elasticsearch/channels`?

Comment: Sorry for delay, your query worked, the problem was my data .. its good now, thank you for helpe me.

Comment: Btw, I also had problem with that structure of query, but when I replaced `OR NOT(_exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)` with `OR (NOT _exists_:channel.schedule.creation_date)` it works fine for me. Small nuance, but took some time.